# Create tf.train.Feature using n-dimensional tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to create a `tf.train.Feature` that contains a tensor instead of a simple 1-d array.

The code I tried is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
data = np.random.randint(0, 100, [8,8,19])
def create_int_feature(values):
    feature = tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[values]))
    return feature
create_int_feature(data)
```

But I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-ddac8a911243> in <module>
      5     feature = tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[values]))
      6     return feature
----> 7 create_int_feature(data)
<ipython-input-16-ddac8a911243> in create_int_feature(values)
      3 data = np.random.randint(0, 100, [8,8,19])
      4 def create_int_feature(values):
----> 5     feature = tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[values]))
      6     return feature
      7 create_int_feature(data)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

My question is is it possible to create a tensor feature given the current TensorFlow API? The TF version I tried are 1.12 and 2.1, both not working. Thanks!

Comment: TensorFlow allows only 1-D lists to `tf.train.Feature`. You need to break the tensor into smaller 1-D arrays and then proceed.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, NO it's not possible to create tensor feature.

A Feature can contain an `Int64List` , a `BytesList` , or a `FloatList`.

For example here is the encoding for the actual raw image:

```
tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value =[image]))
```

This will save it into serialized format.